# Oracle Update Query - join of two tables

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

I have two tables, one parent and one child table. Child will have many rows for parent_id. Both table has status column. Possible values are Active and Deleted.

I want to do this. If for a parent id all children have Deleted status, have to mark parent also as Deleted from Active status. Can it be done in single update query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bear in mind that if Session 'A' has inserted but not committed a new 'Active' record, Session 'B' may only see 'Deleted' records. You generally want to avoid this practice in a highly concurrent environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
UPDATE parent_table pt SET deleted = 'Y' WHERE deleted = 'N' AND id NOT IN
    (SELECT parent_id FROM child_table ct WHERE deleted = 'N' AND ct.parent_id = pt.id)
```

Comment: more clever than mine, avoiding subrequest for each record. +1.

Comment: Parent_table entries without any child_table entries would be also marked as deleted

Comment: @schurik: When there is no child, one can say mathematically that all children rows have been marked as deleted, and saying that is not false.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
update parent
   set status = 'Deleted'
 where status = 'Active'
   and not exists ( select null from child
                     where child.id = parent.id
                       and child.status <> 'Deleted')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE parent_table 
set status = 'deleted'
WHERE status = 'active'
  AND id in (
              SELECT parent_id 
              FROM (
                    SELECT 
                            parent_id
                          , count(*)                                          total
                          , sum (CASE staus WHEN 'deleted' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) deleted
                    FROM child_table
                    group by parent_id
              )
              WHERE total = deleted
             )
```